# CTMessageCenter in iOS 9 and Above

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

There once existed and may still exist a part of the private iOS API, in `CoreTelephony`, called `CTMessageCenter`, which was a class that could be used to programmatically send SMS.

I've struggled for a while now trying to figure out if it is possible to use this class on iOS 9, even going so far as to download [these iOS runtime headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers) and attempt to include the framework in my project... it appears as empty after the import. In any case, `CTMessageCenter` seems to have vanished... surely it still exists or has an alternative.

I've tried using selectors, just importing `CTMessageCenter.h`, and probably other things I can't remember... any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: It's still there. You can't use it to send SMS without jailbreak

Comment: @creker could you possibly tell me how to even begin importing the framework/specific header under ios 9?

Comment: `CoreTelephony` is a public framework. Import it like any other framework in xcode, include `CTMessageCenter.h`. That's it.

Comment: `@import CoreTelephony;`
`#import <CoreTelephony/CTMessageCenter.h>`
gives the error: " 'CoreTelephony/CTMessageCenter.h' file not found" in Xcode 7

Comment: @creker sorry for my nooby reply without tagging you... I can't seem to import the darn header. do you have any advice? I've looked in the SDK folder and it does not even have `CTMessageCenter.h` and including it from the iOS runtime headers doesn't function. I'm using `sendSMSWithText:` and it doesn't actually send anything. perhaps `ChatKit` would be the way to go?